# Update information issue

Tags: updates

How do I stop this message appearing every time I start ubuntu?

"Update info.
Failed to download additional data files.
ttf-mscorefonts-installer"

I already clicked on "Exec this action now" but is not solving.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not accept the license.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

When screen with the license appears, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept.